# Getting the letters from one index to another in a string using C#

Tags: c#, string, slice

I've been trying to make a small function which makes the first letter of a word uppercase, and the rest lowercase. I've found that I need to get the letters from index 1 to the length of the string, but I haven't found a way to do it.

Here's an example:

```
string GetName(string name)
{
    string newName = name[0].ToUpper();
    // join newName with the rest which was converted to lowercase
    return newName;
}
```

I have tried to find a solution online, but I have only found a way to get a the rest of a string after a letter. (note: I have realised a way to do this without a function like this, but I would still like this for future projects)

Comment: Use Substring, or a range operator.

Comment: We don't put "solved" in the title.  Accepting the answer is good enough.

Comment: @LarsTech Okay, I've seen others do it so I thought it would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using traditional string methods:

```
var newName = char.ToUpper(name[0]) + name.Substring(1).ToLower();
```

or

```
var newName = name.Substring(0,1).ToUpper() + name.Substring(1).ToLower();
```

With the proposed slicer syntax:

```
var newName = name[0..1].ToUpper() + name[1..].ToLower();
```

Answer (score 1):

Other options so far allocate memory for each substring used along the way, and copy data to the newly allocated memory each time... typically three total allocations and equivalent of two full copies and traversals of the data (because two of the allocations have accompanying copy/traversals for different portions of the full data).

The option below will likely perform much better, as it only needs one memory allocation in total to create the final string, and only writes the final data once with no other intermediate copying.

```
string GetName(string name)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) return string.Empty;

    return string.Create(name.Length, name, (output, input) => {
        output[0] = input[0].ToUpper();
        for(int i = 1; i<input.Length; i++)
        {
           output[i] = input[i].ToLower();
        }   
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally this was done with Substring, but the range operator has simplified the syntax significantly:

```
string GetName(string name) => name[0..1].ToUpper() + name[1..];
```

Of course, this presupposes that `name` is a string with non-zero length. Consider your use case and add logic to throw an exception or return an acceptable value when that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```cs
string GetName(string name)
{
    if (name != null) {
        Char[] na = name.ToCharArray();
        na[0] = Char.ToUpper(na[0]);
        return new string(na);
    } else
        return name;
}
```

Comment: This is better than most of the other answers (two allocations and data traversals instead of three), but it fails the requirement to make "the rest lowercase", and we can still do better for performance.